# Deploying a Gulp app to Heroku in a subdirectory

Tags: node.js, heroku, gulp

I'm trying to deploy a Rails/Angular app to Heroku.

Part of my directory structure looks like this:

```
client/package.json
client/gulpfile.js
```

My `package.json` and `gulpfile.js` aren't at the root; they're in a subdirectory.

The Heroku Node buildpack of course expects `package.json` to be at the root. How can I get Heroku to recognize my Gulp/Angular app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a custom buildpack to build your front end: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#composing-multiple-buildpacks. You'd compose this custom buildpack with the Rails buildpack to get a complete build working.

The `nodejs` buildpack has examples on how to [run `npm install`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/b5d7dfc63b2e4c6f9d5f75189dc33e34d6027f71/lib/dependencies.sh#L10) and [load `package.json`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/compile#L73) which may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up forking and modifying the Node buildpack and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it without a custom buildpack:

1. Add the node heroku buildpack

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
   ```
2. Add a package.json to the root of your rails project.
3. Add a `postinstall` or a `heroku-postbuild` script to the top-level package.json like this:

   ```
   //top-level package.json
   "scripts": {
     "postinstall": "cd client && npm install && gulp build"
   }
   ```
4. Add client/node_modules to the Heroku cache by adding this to the top-level package.json:

   ```
   //top-level package.json
   "cacheDirectories": ["client/node_modules"]
   ```
5. Enjoy

> Source:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process